# Choosing a file from explorer and insert his name to python kivy app

Tags: python, windows, kivy

I am creating a desktop application using kivy and I need
open an explorer to select a file inside the application so that the user can select a photo.

In kivy there is no built-in functionality that allows you to implement such an explorer (there is a `filechooser`, but I need
built into the OS - such as explorer.exe)

When using the second window of another framework - `tkinter`, `wx`, `easygui`, there are problems with the window focus when
the explorer is open, when you click not on it, the focus remains on it, but it closes and is impossible

access the application. Also, when using a third-party framework, the application closes without
error logs (for example, `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005))`.

Also, I know about the option using drag-and-drop in kivy, but it seems to me not the best idea.
In general, is it possible in kivy to open the explorer to select a file by the user, while avoiding the above errors?

Comment: Have you tried [plyer](https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ? It is cross platform and it got a filechooser

Comment: filechooser from plyer works, thank you

Comment: Yay ~ welcome  : )